# Ubuntu can't boot

Tags: boot, usb, lubuntu

I am trying to install Ubuntu on [this](http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/document?docname=c00248307&tmp_task=prodinfoCategory&cc=us&dlc=en&lc=en&product=375243) old laptop(I now have 502 MB of RAM). I first tried Ubuntu but when running live from usb, it gave me an error:

> BusyBox v1.22.1 ......(there is some things written here...)
>
> Enter 'help' for a list of built in commands
>
> (initramfs) mount: mounting /dev/loop0 on //filesystem.squashfs
> failed: No such device
>
> Can not mount /dev/lop0 (cdrom/casper/filesystem.squashfs) on //filesystem.squashfs

I saw Lubuntu and tried it still it gave me the same error(I copied the above error from Lubuntu but I am 99 % sure it was the exact same error for Ubuntu). Any idea what to do?

Comment: How did you make the live usb?

Comment: It looks like a DVD.

Comment: I used this program: http://www.pendrivelinux.com/universal-usb-installer-easy-as-1-2-3/

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have any important files or other OS-es on your PC, why don't you just use GParted and format the whole thing? Also, Live CD/DVDs are a lot more efficient, based on my Lubuntu install with both USB and DVD.

Personal opinion: Pick Lubuntu over Ubuntu, it's a lot faster for older PCs like yours. Trust me, I got a 12 year old one ;)

Comment: Sorry to respond to an old question, shortly after asking this, got really occupied and forgot that old laptop. The thing is, I can't boot the OS to install it on the PC, it give me this error. Also, GParted is not working, similar problem.